# Stamp Contact Record based on contact being added to a Campaign as a Campaign Member

Tags: campaign-member

I want to update a field(s) on the related Contact record each time they are added to a campaign so we can attribute donated funds to the correct campaign when no other identifier is given.

As a charity we get a huge amount of unspecified web donations and we would like to automate allocating the funds to the correct campaign. As Salesforce does not allow you to do field updates from the Campaign Member object back to the Contact record how can this be achieved in a in an automated way?